# Extract words/sentence that occurs before a keyword from a string - Python

Tags: python, regex, keyword, matching

I have a string like this,

```
my_str ='·in this match, dated may 1, 2013 (the "the match") is between brooklyn centenniel, resident of detroit, michigan ("champion") and kamil kubaru, the challenger from alexandria, virginia ("underdog").'
```

Now, I want to extract the current `champion` and the `underdog` using keywords `champion` and `underdog` .

What is really challenging here is both contender's names appear before the keyword inside parenthesis. I want to use regular expression and extract information.

Following is what I did,

```
champion = re.findall(r'("champion"[^.]*.)', my_str)
print(champion)

>> ['"champion") and kamil kubaru, the challenger from alexandria, virginia ("underdog").']


underdog = re.findall(r'("underdog"[^.]*.)', my_str)
print(underdog)

>>['"underdog").']
```

However, I need the results, `champion as`:

```
brooklyn centenniel, resident of detroit, michigan
```

and the `underdog` as:

`kamil kubaru, the challenger from alexandria, virginia`

How can I do this using regular expression? (I have been searching, if I could go back couple or words from the keyword to get the result I want, but no luck yet) Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named captured group to capture the desired results:

```
between\s+(?P<champion>.*?)\s+\("champion"\)\s+and\s+(?P<underdog>.*?)\s+\("underdog"\)
```

- `between\s+(?P<champion>.*?)\s+\("champion"\)` matches the chunk from `between` to `("champion")` and put the desired portion in between as the named captured group `champion`
- After that, `\s+and\s+(?P<underdog>.*?)\s+\("underdog"\)` matches the chunk upto `("underdog")` and again get the desired portion from here as named captured group `underdog`

**Example:**

```
In [26]: my_str ='·in this match, dated may 1, 2013 (the "the match") is between brooklyn centenniel, resident of detroit, michigan ("champion") and kamil kubaru, the challenger from alexandria, virginia 
    ...: ("underdog").'

In [27]: out = re.search(r'between\s+(?P<champion>.*?)\s+\("champion"\)\s+and\s+(?P<underdog>.*?)\s+\("underdog"\)', my_str)

In [28]: out.groupdict()
Out[28]: 
{'champion': 'brooklyn centenniel, resident of detroit, michigan',
 'underdog': 'kamil kubaru, the challenger from alexandria, virginia'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be a better answer than this, and I don't know regex at all, but I'm bored, so here's my 2 cents.

Here's how I would go about it:

```
words = my_str.split()
index = words.index('("champion")')
champion = words[index - 6:index]
champion = " ".join(champion)
```

for the underdog, you will have to change the 6 to a 7, and `'("champion")'` to `'("underdog").'`

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but for this particular string, this worked when I tested it.

You could also use [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) to remove punctuation if that trailing period on underdog is a problem.

Comment: What output is it giving you?

Comment: `print(champion)` gives me `'ch, da'`

Comment: oops.  See my edit.  One instance of `my_str` has been replaced by `words`